# Bootstrap radio button already checked not worked

Tags: php, html

This is my code of radio button i want image radio buttton is alredy check but it's not working

```
<div class="col-md-4" style="padding-top: 24px;" >
    <label>Visual</label>
    <div>
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" value="image" checked="checked" name="media_option[]" class="media_option"  autocomplete="off"><?php echo  __('Image') ?> 
        </label>&nbsp;
        <label>or</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input value="video" type="radio" name="media_option[]" class="media_option"  autocomplete="off" ><?php echo  __('Video') ?>
        </label>
    </div>
```

Comment: your code working fine:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/44756901/4248328

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

Don't set radio name as array and not need to set autocomplete attribute.

```
 <div class="col-md-4" style="padding-top: 24px;" >
        <label>Visual</label>
    <div>
       <label class="radio-inline">
       <input type="radio" value="image" name="media_option" class="media_option" checked="checked" ><?php echo  __('Image') ?> 
        </label>&nbsp;
        <label>or</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input value="video" type="radio" name="media_option" class="media_option" ><?php echo  __('Video') ?>
        </label>
    </div>
```

Comment: It's a duplicate of my answer.

Comment: check name attribute

Comment: Can't really see what changing the name attribute does to make the radio input checked on default, oh well.

Comment: name="media_option"  and you used name="media_option[]"

Comment: ...that really should not matter, besides, it is based off the code he has posted. Removing those brackets can break his code as he might be using them to combine those 2 inputs together if I am not mistaken

Comment: please also check my post time and you post time must be same so why are  you say i copied your answer

Comment: Thank you i have got solutions

Comment: Posted like 30 seconds earlier, useless anyway as there are so many duplicate answers and OP does not seem like he is going to accept an answer anytime soon.

Comment: please avoid extra discussion and i don`t need to copy your answer please compare your answer  line to line code   with my answer i hope you get your mistake

Answer (score 1):

Its working fine, check here:

```html
<input type="radio" value="image" checked="checked" name="media_option[]" class="media_option"  autocomplete="off">One
<input type="radio" value="image" checked="checked" name="media_option[]" class="media_option"  autocomplete="off">Two
```

when you are using radio, only one radio can be selected within one group (having same name). The same is working here.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?
This will always work

```
<input type="radio" value="image" checked="checked" name="media_option[]" class="media_option"  autocomplete="off">
```

If not try this

```
<input checked type="radio" value="image" name="media_option[]" class="media_option"  autocomplete="off">
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change the checked="checked" to checked  only :

Here is the code ,please try:

```
 <div class="col-md-4" style="padding-top: 24px;" >
    <label>Visual</label>
    <div>
       <label class="radio-inline">
       <input type="radio" value="image" checked name="media_option[]" class="media_option"  autocomplete="off"><?php echo  __('Image') ?> 
       </label>&nbsp;
       <label>or</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
       <label class="radio-inline">
       <input value="video" type="radio" name="media_option[]" class="media_option"  autocomplete="off" ><?php echo  __('Video') ?>
       </label>
     /div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I came here because I had the same issue and without seeing the rest of the code in the question, won't make any assumptions.

However, if the code above wasn't within a form element, that could have caused the issue.

That was the issue in my case, after placing the radio elements within the form, the checked attribute worked again as expected. Hopefully this helps someone else out as well.